# Elixir/Phoenix not saving data to the Database

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I don't understand why my query *appears* to run okay, but when I look into the DB, I can find no such record(s) - my loop is inserting 37 records in total - and none of them are actually in the DB!?

I know I am connecting to the DB okay because I query the data fine on other pages of my Phoenix application.

Does anyone have any ideas I can investigate?

mix phx.server output:

```
begin []
[debug] QUERY OK db=0.2ms
INSERT INTO `activities` (`days_coding`,`days_done`,`days_merged`,`days_pending_release`,`days_pending_review`,`days_ready_for_qa`,`days_requires_discussion`,`days_selected_for_development`,`days_testing`,`new`,`sprint_id`,`stage`,`stage_date`,`ticket_id`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [10, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 26, 45, 0, false, 10, "Ready for QA", {2018, 8, 13}, 184]
[debug] QUERY OK db=0.4ms
commit []
%Ptrack.Youtrack.Activity{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "activities">,
  days_coding: 10,
  days_done: 0,
  days_merged: 0,
  days_pending_release: 0,
  days_pending_review: 4,
  days_ready_for_qa: 8,
  days_requires_discussion: 26,
  days_selected_for_development: 45,
  days_testing: 0,
  id: 7500,
  new: false,
  sprint_id: 10,
  stage: "Ready for QA",
  stage_date: ~D[2018-08-13],
  ticket: %Ptrack.Youtrack.Ticket{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "tickets">,
    aha_ref: nil,
    assignee: "wilmer",
    id: 184,
    summary: "VMS (Prod)  - Able to delete a vendor with entities ",
    ticket: "SN-204",
    ticket_type: "Bug"
  },
  ticket_id: 184
}
```

Comment: Please show more code. Does it happen in transaction? If so it can be rolled back if some error occurs aside of successful queries.

Comment: I would try to include full logging in the database and look at the log after performing the insertion operation